# How to write a GraphQL query to retrieve all the workflows/runs from github

Tags: github, graphql, github-actions

How to write a GraphQL query  to retrieve all the workflows/runs from github
I tried below query for to get node id

```
organization(login: "abc") {
        repositories(first: 100) {
            nodes {
                    id
                    name
                    }
                }
            }
```

and below query to get workflow.

```
    nodes(ids: "sdefrgrt") {
        ... on Workflow {
          id
          createdAt
          name
          updatedAt
        }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for similar info ("how to get workflow runs for a repo via GraphQL") and couldn't find it, but the REST API has what you want: https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflow-runs?apiVersion=2022-11-28#list-workflow-runs-for-a-repository

Comment: Thank you for helping. I did use REST APIs and my app is ready already.

Answer (score 3):

You may get the workflow runs via:

```
     {
      node(id: "YOUR-WORKFLOW-NODE-ID") {
        ... on Workflow {
          runs(first: 10) {
            nodes {
              runNumber
              createdAt
              checkSuite {
                commit {
                  message
                  associatedPullRequests(first: 1) {
                    nodes {
                      number
                    }
                  }
                  history {
                    nodes {
                      author {
                        date
                        email
                        name
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Workflow's node_id could be taken from https://docs.github.com/en/rest/actions/workflows?apiVersion=2022-11-28#get-a-workflow

Comment: Just adding a link to GitHub docs about global ids and how to get them from REST, and use them in graphQL. https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/using-global-node-ids

Answer (score 3):

Top-level GitHub Actions access (instead of going through `pullRequest`, which is incomplete) is [not available](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24493#discussioncomment-3244259). The [roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/github/projects/4247/views/1?filterQuery=graphql) doesn't mention *future* plans regarding GraphQL and GitHub Actions. Neither does the [changelog](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/changelog), looking into the *past*. Lastly, the *present* state doesn't mention GitHub Actions in its [schema](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/public-schema) either (not as a top-level concept anyway).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this should be available via GraphQL (you can try this query out with [Github's GraphQL explorer](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/explorer)):

```
{
  repository(owner: "$ORG", name: "$REPO") {
    pullRequest(number: $NUMBER) {
      commits(first: 5) {
        edges {
          node {
            commit {
              checkSuites(first: 5) {
                nodes {
                  workflowRun {
                    url
                    workflow {
                      name
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'd adjust the `first` parameters, and the client would need to do some grouping on the data that comes back from GraphQL.

Comment: Careful, doing it this way only gets you workflows based on a pull request. But you can have workflows that are not associated with pull requests at all.